# Заменить класс и удалить атрибут у всех <select> на странице

Tags: атрибуты

Помогите пожалуйста. На странице товара в интернет магазине могут выводится select с классом "inputbox" и атрибутом size="..." Из-за прописанного в движке магазина класса идет конфликт в стилизации элемента. Нужно заменить класс и удалить атрибут (если есть) у всех таких селектов. Насмотрелся/начитался примеров, но всё не то, а самому "соченить" не выходит...

```
Этот код работает:
<script>
document.[какая-то функция]('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for (var i = selects.length - 1; i >= 0; --i){
    selects[i].classList.add('uk-select');
    selects[i].removeAttribute('size');
} 
});
</script>
```

Но при попытке добавить такую же функцию на корректировку input-ов, выдает ошибку. Меняется класс у последнего на страницу input и все. атрибут не удаляет и к следующему input не переходит. Что не так?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for (var i = selects.length - 1; i >= 0; --i){
    selects[i].className='uk-select';
    selects[i].removeAttribute('size');
} 

 var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('inputbox');
    for (var i = inputs.length - 1; i >= 0; --i){
    inputs[i].className='uk-inputbox';
    inputs[i].removeAttribute('size');
} 
});
</script>
```

Comment: какую именно ошибку выдает?

Comment: [ссылка](https://prnt.sc/th3919)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта функция называется [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) - она позволяет добавлять обработчики событий.

1. Первый параметр - название события
2. Второй - Функция обработчик
3. Третий - настройки.

---

Методы `.getElementsBy*` возвращают живые коллекции, которые обновляются сразу же, как элемент начинает или перестает соответствовать условию для выборки.

Таким образом, если элементу добавить класс, то он автоматически добавится в коллекцию, полученную с помощью `getElementsByClassName`, аналогично, в случае удаления - удалится.

Это можно проследить на пример с инпутами:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('inputbox');

for (i = inputs.length - 1; i >= 0; --i){
    inputs[i].className='uk-inputbox';
    inputs[i].removeAttribute('size');
}
```

1. В коллекции `inputs` находятся все инпуты с классом `inputbox`
2. берем `inputs[i]` и заменяем его класс `inputbox` на 'uk-inputbox'
3. так как теперь инпут не соответствует выборке (у него нет класса 'inputbox'), он автоматически удалился из коллекции.
4. пробуем обратиться по тому же индексу, но, так как элемент был последним - выходим за границы коллекции.

Для решения достаточно сохранить инпут в переменную:

```
for (var i = inputs.length - 1; i >= 0; --i){
    var input = inputs[i];
    input.className='uk-inputbox';
    input.removeAttribute('size');
}
```

Либо поменять местами действия и менять класс перед переходом следующему элементу:

```
for (var i = inputs.length - 1; i >= 0; --i){
    inputs[i].removeAttribute('size');
    inputs[i].className='uk-inputbox';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Да, я так и писал, но не заработало. Подумал, не правильно. Проблема ошибке. "index >= 0" забыл index на "i" заменить.

Comment: @Константин, еще стоит  не терять `var` при объявлении в цикле: `for (i = selects.length - 1;`

Comment: Не понял, что вы имеете ввиду. Что-то не правильно?

Comment: @Константин, у тебя `i` утекла в глобальную область видимости, это может привести к интересным результатам

Comment: добавить в код 
 var i; ?

Comment: @Константин, `for (var i = `

Comment: Поправил код. Всё равно, не работает

Comment: @Константин, обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо. логику понял. Работает!

Comment: @Константин, с селектами все работает, потому ты для них используешь `getElementsByTagName`, а для инпутов: `getElementsByClassName`. Изменить тег элемента - проблематично, а вот изменить класс - легко